# Python: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list; Problems with datatypes and numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, mongodb, numpy

I know there are a few similar questions in here but none of them helped me.. at least I didn´t find any..

I load Data from my MongoDB and store it in a List of up to 200 integers.. 1 dimensional. In the Example i use just 10.

I already tried to np.array(X) it but that doesn't work either.

I'm just learning things, pls be gentle.

```
import numpy as np

X =  [538, 561, 500, 559, 545, 559, 579, 549, 542, 524]

# Y     I load the data from a textfile with numpy.loadtext
# Y =  [33. 16. 32. 51. 27. 16. 34. 17. 29. 15.]



Z, Y = np.loadtxt("data/textfile.txt", skiprows=1, unpack=True)


def predict(X):
    return X * 1 + 2

def loss(X, Y):
    return np.average((predict(X - Y)**2)


def train(X, Y, iterations):
    for i in range (iterations):
        current_loss = loss(X, Y)

test, test2 = train(X, Y, iterations=1000)
```

Textfile

```
data1  data2
13            33
2             16
14            32
23            51
13            27
1             16
18            34
10            17
26            29
3             15
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\..., line 18, in <module>
    w, b = linear_regression.train(X, Y, iterations=1000000, lr=0.001)
  File "C:\...\linear_regression.py", line 16, in train
    current_loss = loss(X, Y, w, b)
  File "C:\...linear_regression.py", line 10, in loss
    return np.average((predict(X, w, b) - Y) ** 2)
  File "C:\...linear_regression.py", line 6, in predict
    return X * w + b
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
X =  [538, 561, 500, 559, 545, 559, 579, 549, 542, 524]
Y =  [33. 16. 32. 51. 27. 16. 34. 17. 29. 15.]
```

These are the prints of my X & Y ..

How can i convert X in the format of Y?

Comment: In all likelihood, your problem is in this function.  It appears you are trying to add together a scalar and a list.  I believe X is the list, but can't say for sure without seeing more detail and data       `def predict(X, w, b):    return X * w + b`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*, so we are not interested in your level of experience; we are interested in *the question*. If you already tried to find questions but they didn't help you, please a) explicitly show which questions you found; b) explain exactly why they didn't help you.

Comment: Reason why you should provide the full error traceback

Comment: In particular, make sure your question is focused on *the actual problem*. If you are able to read the numbers you want from the database, and `X` and `Y` look like what you want them to, then leave that part out - instead, show code that just assigns those values directly. Instead of showing the complete data from your actual file, show a small bit of data *that will cause the problem*. Similarly, if `train` works, then just assign the corresponding `w` and `b` values - and make sure that you can reproduce the problem this way.

Comment: By following these steps, you also automatically start to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code, i.e. to try to find and understand the problem yourself. This is where you should start, always. Come to Stack Overflow when you cannot solve the problem; show us the part that you cannot solve; and show us enough to understand that problem but no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with the array. I solved it myself. I feel dumb now.

I just had to convert the X into a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

X =  [538, 561, 500, 559, 545, 559, 579, 549, 542, 524]

# Y     I load the data from a textfile with numpy.loadtext
# Y =  [33. 16. 32. 51. 27. 16. 34. 17. 29. 15.]



Z, Y = np.loadtxt("data/textfile.txt", skiprows=1, unpack=True)


def predict(X):
    return X * 1 + 2

def loss(X, Y):
    return np.average((predict(X - Y)**2)


def train(X, Y, iterations):
    for i in range (iterations):
        current_loss = loss(X, Y)
X = np.asarray(X)



test, test2 = train(X, Y, iterations=1000)
```